Angular web app conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-16
What will be required changes to add support of UTF-16 to an Angular 14 web app ?
Currently, its UTF-8 and I have made the changes within html meta for UTF-16 as below,
<meta charset="UTF-16">

to save the files i.e. for css and other ts files, I tried using Byte Order Mark (BOM) from VS Code but on saving it converts the file data into another character and on saving back to UTF-8, it doesn't works, attached below the reference image,
encoding to UTF-16
I tried research on google as I got the below answer
Angular does not support the @charset UTF-16 meta tag
Can any one explain Angular supports UTF-16 if yes how to proceed with the approach, if No then the explanation ?
Tried BOM(Byte Order Mark) i.e. save with encoding in text editor(VS Code) with UTF-16 LE, but it converts the file data into unnecessary characters, attached reference image below,
enter image description here
Expectation :
On encoding it should save the file with UTF-16 support and on saving the file back with UTF-8 its vice-versa,
Using Angular v12

Keep using UTF-8 Everywhere… Please do not use (sole) images of code/data/errors in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code. Post a hexadecimal dump in case of (partially) binary content.
